# Detecting new changes in a zipped.Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am looking to detect new changes in a combinedLatest Observable. Both of the original Observable streams are long-lived, and I would like to detect if the change added a new item, or removed an item in the combinedLatest Observable, but I'm not exactly sure how to compare the new combinedLatest observable values to the old ones before the change.

```
      this.friendsOnMap$ = combineLatest(this.friendsOnlyPeople$, this.friends$)
  .pipe(map(([friendsOnlyPeople, friends]) => friendsOnlyPeople
  .map(this.checkIfFriend(friends))))
  .map(friend => {
    return friend.filter(friend => friend.isFriend == true);
  })
  .subscribe(friends => {
    console.log('Combined$ ', friends)
  });
```

Currently, this runs `console.log('Combined$ ', friends)` every single time the Observable changes. But I would like to only run this if a new item is added or removed.

Comment: You're using pipable and patch operators together or what is it? I don't understand where these four `))))` come from in `.map(this.checkIfFriend(friends))))`

Comment: This is just how I got it to work correctly, I want to checkIfFriend, which then returns the items mapped with a value of .isFriend = true or false, and then I'm mapping those, and filtering out the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [distinctUntilChanged](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html) and passing a custom `compare` function... in your case returning `true` if no friends have been added or deleted:

```
this.friendsOnMap$ = combineLatest(this.friendsOnlyPeople$, this.friends$).pipe(
  map(([friendsOnlyPeople, friends]) => friendsOnlyPeople.map(this.checkIfFriend(friends))),
  map((friends: Friend[]) => friends.filter(friend => friend.isFriend == true)),
  distinctUntilChanged((p: Friend[], q: Friend[]) => {
    // return true if p and q are the same set of identities
    ...
  })
).subscribe(friends => {
  console.log('Combined$ ', friends)
});
```